# How can I switch between content on the same page using HTML/CSS/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show different content for when the user switches between different month/year options within the same page. e.g. I want to show the user events for the month of March 2021 if he /she chooses that option. Attached is the screenshot for reference of how I want the UI to look like.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking this community to make this web page? That's not how it works, you're not recruiting freelancers, if you have a problem with the page you're creating post your code with a question about what you can't do.

Comment: I'm sorry, noted on your feedback! Will work on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, doing this with vanilla html,css,js is pretty hard. What you can do is using a `<div>` for every month and use css to set all of them to `display: none` except the one that should be shown. Then you could attach an `onclick` listener to your two arrow keys. With javascript you can then make your current month `<div>` hidden and show your next month with `display: block`. You have to watch out that all your seperate month containers are `position: absolute` at exactly the same place.

Watch out, this is a really **not ideal solution** especially if you have a lot of containers.

The **proper way to do this** would be using something like `ReactJS` or you could also try `Ajax`. Both allow you to change part of your website without having to reload it completely.

This is just how you can do it. Don't expect anyone on the forum here to do the work for you. If you have specific questions or problems, feel free to ask but this is not a platform to get free workers.

Comment: Using Ajax also does not change the url of the webpage? So I just query whenever the user changes the month using the arrow? Is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: That is true, if you want to have the url change when clicking on the arrows Ajax isn't a solution. Then I would personally use React with React-Router

Comment: Okay, I will probably have to use Ajax in this case then, since I do not want the url to change everytime the person chooses the month

Comment: Good, please mark this answer as accepted then by clicking on the check mark so your question won't be displayed to other people anymore.